# How store data changes in SQL Server as JSON format?

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I am transitioning an *old format* for data changes to a newer format in JSON in SQL Server 2022. I need to log what changes were made to existing data, and who made them.

The *old/current data* format stores info about User, Id, and what changes made to the data, e.g.:

```
u=[m,id:1],  [Name]=([Old name] : [New name])  [Address]=([1 Old street] : [500 New street])
```

I need to transition this format to JSON for ease of consumption in the .NET 8.0 application. I thought about doing something like this (any inputs are welcome):

**Desired JSON format**

```
SET @json = N'[{
        "req": { "type": "m", "id": 1, "via" : "website"},
        "log": {
                 "name":{ "o":"Old name", "n":"New name" },
                 "address":{ "o":"Old address", "n":"500 New street" }
               }
    }]';
```

I figure I need to use `FOR JSON PATH` in SQL Server have never worked with that, so how can this be done the most efficient way?

**UPDATE 1**:
temporal tables will not work for this problem / storage cost is a factor and existing data models will need to change.

**Pseudo logic:**

```
if data has changed
create JSON root doc
add JSON user details to root doc
foreach data change, append changelog to root doc
```

**UPDATE 2:** Using `FOR JSON PATH` I have arrived to this solution.
As can be seen the code is quite repetitive doing the same checks several times. If anybody can suggest an optimized version, I will award the answer.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Data    
CREATE TABLE #Data (
    Id int primary key,
    Name nvarchar(255), 
    Address nvarchar(255)
)

INSERT INTO #Data (Id,Name,Address) VALUES (1,'Old name','Old address')

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TempLog
CREATE TABLE #TempLog (
    DataId int,
    LogChanges NVARCHAR(max)
);

declare @id int = 1
declare @Name nvarchar(255) = 'New name'
declare @Address nvarchar(255) = '500 New street'

INSERT INTO #TempLog (DataId,LogChanges)
SELECT 
    123,
    (SELECT  
        'm' AS 'req.type',
        @id as 'req.id',
        'website' AS 'req.via',
        IIF(ISNULL(@Name,'')<>ISNULL([Name],''), [Name],NULL) as 'log.name.o',
        IIF(ISNULL(@Name,'')<>ISNULL([Name],''), @Name,NULL) as 'log.name.n', 
        IIF(ISNULL(@Address,'')<>ISNULL([Address],''), [Address],NULL) as 'log.address.o',
        IIF(ISNULL(@Address,'')<>ISNULL([Address],''), @Address,NULL) as 'log.address.n'    
    FROM 
        #Data
    WHERE  
        Id = @id
        AND (
                (@Name<>[Name] OR ISNULL(@Name,'')<>ISNULL([Name],''))
                OR (@Address<>[Address] OR ISNULL(@Address,'')<>ISNULL([Address],''))
            )
    FOR JSON PATH);
```

The JSON produced with the `FOR JSON PATH:`

```javascript
    [
       {
          "req":{
             "type":"m", "id":1,"via":"website"
          },
          "log":{
             "name":{"o":"Old name","n":"New name"},
             "address":{"o":"Old address","n":"500 New street"}
          }
       }
    ]
```

Comment: Wouldn't it make *more* sense to use temporal tables? Then, if you do need (historical )JSON for *something* you can get that data from the history table.

Comment: or you know, use something called columns to store old / new data

Comment: Another vote for temporal tables here.

Comment: Further to my comment, if you need the historical data to all be using the same methodolgy you could even `INSERT` that data into your history table provided you still have it available (including in your JSON) and know the validatity date(times) of that data.

Comment: @ThomA - I wasn't aware of temporal tables even existed but looking at it, perhaps this is the way to go.

Comment: @siggemannen - I am not sure exactly what you mean / or if you are being sarcastic ;) - the example above is for illustration and of course I am not using temp tables for this exercise.

Comment: i mean you could create a table called changes (id int, oldName nvarchar(100), newName nvarchar(100), oldSomethingElse INT, newSomethingElse INT) and log there

Comment: @siggemannen I understand now what you meant. I think that is a difficult format to maintain, and you end up with lot of columns that will be `null`. Not sure if it's the same way temporal tables work though, i.e. storing a lot of `nulls` for non-changes.

Comment: Temporal tables mirror the live table for every row, so duplicate the data as it was between the valid-from / valid-to times.  They are very easy to set up and query with some dedicated t-sql syntax if you choose, try them. Put them in a dedicated filegroup and store somewhere dedicated if necessary.

Comment: @Stu - to understand this correctly - will the whole row be duplicated into the temporal row, or is it just the delta value(s)? In my case, I just need to record the delta. Data storage costs matter too.
Temporal tables look great but when you have additional tables with additional data related to the main data, then I see some challenges. I update a value in a related table , then this will be not recorded on the main table.  To see diffs I need to join on the two tables (both being temporal).

Comment: Temporal tables provide you with a snapshot of the data, as it was, at a point in time, for that row. You may want this, you may not, ie ymmv; with a snapshot, you can compute the delta changes for any column.

Comment: I think temporal tables will not be optimal for my situation, looking at data costs, changing existing data models etc. Original question stands.